# Solve issue - unresolved external symbol MFCreateDXGIDeviceManagerv

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I want to capture video using Media Foundation transform library.

I have used

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevel;
ID3D11DeviceContext* pDX11DeviceContext;

hr = CreateDX11Device(&g_pDX11Device, &pDX11DeviceContext, &FeatureLevel);


if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&g_ResetToken, &g_pDXGIMan);
}
```

On building the vcpp application I received error:

```
unresolved external symbol MFCreateDXGIDeviceManagerv
```

For this, I used

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mf") // For MFEnumDevices
#pragma comment(lib, "mfplat")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfreadwrite")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxva2")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
#pragma comment(lib, "mfuuid")
```

to include libraries related to MFCreateDXGIDeviceManagerv. Still I am getting same error.
Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager is in MshtmlMedia.dll on Windows 7, and in the MFPlat.dll on Windows 8 and higher.

Comment: I included MFPlat.dll in my application and still facing same issue.

Comment: I assume you are on the Win8+ then. What SDK version do you have? Can you make sure that the mfplat.lib is accessible by your linker, and there are no unprinted characters in the method name?

Comment: Thanks Aleksey for the idea. Successfully solved the issue. I need to add library directory path in the application property.